# Difference of [nsmutablearray removeAllObjects] and [nsmutablearray release]

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, release

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do removeAllObjects and release of an NSMutableArray both have the same functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164154/do-removeallobjects-and-release-of-an-nsmutablearray-both-have-the-same-functiona)

The difference of `[nsmutablearray removeAllObjects]` and `[nsmutablearray release]`?

Waiting for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First off, both the methods you're asking about are instance methods, not class methods. i.e., they can only be called on instances of the NSMutableArray class--

```
NSMutableArray* i = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
[i removeAllObjects];
```

or,

```
NSMutableArray* j = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
[j release];
```

`removeAllObjects`, well, empties the array, and sends a `release` message to each object removed from the array. However, the array object itself still exists and you could add items to it in the future by executing `[i addObject:obj]` where obj is a valid object.

`release` on the other hand, relinquishes control of the array object, and decrements its retain count by 1. When the retain count of an object hits 0, it'll be deallocated from memory. Deallocation of the array object would cause a `release` message being sent to each of the objects stored in the array.

The `arrayWithCapacity` method creates `i` as an autoreleased object, and you don't call `release` on it. If you do so and this causes the object to be `dealloc`-ed, it would cause an exception later on when the `NSAutoReleasePool` object sends it a `release` message.